# What other software can do the same things as MS Access?

Tags: microsoft-access

Is there any other good software that allows users to easily create tables and attach them to editable forms?

Answer (score 5):

There is the OpenOffice Version of Access called OpenOffice.org Base. I have not worked with it yet, but I assume it´s pretty much the same and OpenSource.

Comment: Yes it's pretty much the same except everything is different, just like all the OOo applications. (Don't expect *MS Access for Dummies* to guide you.) Still, if you don't mind getting your head around the differences, OOo is a great choice, and FREE!

Answer (score 1):

The only real competitor to Access is FileMaker Pro, and it is quite limited in programmability (compared to Access) and doesn't really support SQL.